# A classe DateTime do PHP suporta a criação de data no formato brasileiro?

Tags: php, datetime, diff

No código a seguir **echo** estar imprimindo +273 days, mas o certo não seria **+9 dias**?

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('01/04/2018');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10/04/2018');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Estou sem entender a razão, poderia me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 8):

**SIM, ela suporta.**

Para formatar em `DD MM AAAA` você pode usar `-`, `.` e `\t`, mas não `/`:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('01-04-2018'); // poderia ser 01.04.2018 também
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10-04-2018');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/SGESaN)**

Mais detalhes na documentação (vide "Notações Localizadas > Dia, mês e ano"):

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: Nice. Não sabia disso! =)

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode formatar a hora de várias maneiras manipulando esse objeto **DateTime**. A documentação desse método do php traz inúmeras formas de faze-lá.

Mas como a pergunta refere-se ao formato brasileiro aqui vai:

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2011-01-01');
var_dump($datetime2->format('d/m/y'));
```

Saída: `string(8) "01/01/11"`

**Outro exemplo:**

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-01-02');
var_dump($datetime1->format('d*m*y'));
```

Saída: `string(8) "02*01*11"`

Certifique-se de que a hora inserida esteja no padrão: `('ano-mes-dia')`.  *Se não coisas estranhas irão acontecer*.

Agora com os dados em perfeita ordem aplique seus métodos:

```
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Saída:  `1`

Comment: "Certifique-se de que a hora inserida esteja no padrão: ('ano-mes-dia'). Se não coisas estranhas irão acontecer." isso que percebi, mas estava querendo confirmar. então o jeito e converte a data antes. pessoal muito obrigado

Comment: Certifique-se de marcar uma resposta como respondida